# How to get coords of tiles that are currently visible?

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I need to get `x/y` (where x and y are coords that leaflet.js uses to query corresponding url with `x/y/z` for tiles) coords of currently visible tiles.

I want to find a solution without enabling `unloadInvisibleTiles` option.

Is the only way to do this is through `getPixelBounds()`?

**Edit**:
Added an example [gist](http://bl.ocks.org/warmspringwinds/4a9fec9783c4a49ae054).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you have to go through `getPixelBounds()`

You can enumerate them with following code: xTile and yTile are what you are looking for

```
// get bounds, zoom and tileSize        
var bounds = map.getPixelBounds();
var zoom = map.getZoom();
var tileSize = 256;  


// get NorthWest and SouthEast points
var nwTilePoint = new L.Point(Math.floor(bounds.min.x / tileSize),
    Math.floor(bounds.min.y / tileSize));

var seTilePoint = new L.Point(Math.floor(bounds.max.x / tileSize),
    Math.floor(bounds.max.y / tileSize));

// get max number of tiles in this zoom level
var max = map.options.crs.scale(zoom) / tileSize; 

// enumerate visible tiles 
for (var x = nwTilePoint.x; x <= seTilePoint.x; x++) {
   for (var y = nwTilePoint.y; y <= seTilePoint.y; y++) {

      var xTile = (x + max) % max;
      var yTile = (y + max) % max;

      console.log('tile ' + xTile + ' ' + yTile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great code! Thank you!

But there is one corner case.
Make it Math.abs(x%max) and Math.abs(y%max) or you will have negative tile coords sometimes.

Comment: Actually, x and y are always positive in a Mercator projection: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#X_and_Y

Comment: Yes, you are right but getPixelBounds() returns negative x if you scroll your map to the left when the map starts to repeat.

Comment: the method `getPixelBounds ` does not seems to be here in the last version (`version: "0.37.0"`).. so this answer is deprecated. any workaround?

Comment: What are you including ? Current version of leaflet is 1.0.3 and the method is still there: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#map-getpixelbounds.

Comment: Great Solution! Thank you. :)